# convert MenuContainer to Container

Tags: java, jmenu, jmenuitem

I have a Jmenu with Jmenulist. I can access all the components(Jmenulist) of container(JMenu) using

```
for (Component c : mnFile.getMenuComponents())
    {
        System.out.println(c.getName());
    }
```

I have another function which takes in parent container(which has all the other containers, including JMenu) and recursively does something.

```
for (Component c : cont.getComponents()){
/// do something
}
```

This function doesnt identify the Jmenulist items as they can be iterated only by getMenuComponents. Is there any way I can cast the objects or know before hand that its coming Jmenu class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the java operator instanceof to test that the object coming in is a JMenu.

```
Object o = some JMenu

....

if (o instanceof JMenu) {
  JMenu menu = (Jmenu) o;
  ...
}
```